# how to make comment area autoscroll when comments are much

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, facebook

I have some post on which user can comment but sometime when there are more than 5 comments for e.g 25 comments on a single post then it makes my page very heavy and long

This is how my post comment system look like

```
Post 1
Comment for post 1 //if comments are more than 3 
<button class="view_comments" data-id="1">View previous comments</button>
it will show 2 comments by default and a button above this to fetch all comments of this post

Post 2
comment for post 2
```

Now when i click on view previous comment it fetches all comments which take all the space of the page

How can i put these extra comments into scrollable div like facebook and linkedin does

here is the jquery part

```
$(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".view_comments", function() 
{

var ID = $(this).attr("id");

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "https://www.example.com/ajax/viewajax.php",
data: "post_id="+ ID, 
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("#view_comments"+ID).prepend(html);
$("#view"+ID).remove();
$("#two_comments"+ID).remove();
}
});

return false;
});
});
```

Comment: just set a height property on the container div for the comments and that's all. (max-height)

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş thanks max height worked write it as answer so i can upvote

Comment: also look at the other suggestion about overflow-x it will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Set CSS property `max-height` to the container `<div>` that holds the comments and it should at least partially solve your problem.**

Answer (score 1):

It's a CSS question in my opinion.

You can create a div as a placeholder of all comments and set fix height to it, for example 300px. And set overflow-x:hidden in CSS;

```
<div id="comment_placeholder" style="height: 300px; overflow-x: hidden;">
    <!-- append your comments here by jQuery -->
</div>
```